# MySql: order by before group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, sql-order-by, grouping

I am tying to ordering a sub query before grouping it. The problem is that the sub query is order as if we take it just like a query. But as sub query order by does nothing.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
    a.id,
    citypair,
    a.season,
    airline,
    class,
    fare,
    rbd,
    season_from,
    season_to,
    schedule_id,
    cp.departure_id,
    cp.destination_id,
    sch.date_time
FROM tarifftool_price_log as a
JOIN tarifftool_seasons as b ON a.seasonId = b.id
JOIN tarifftool_citypairs as cp ON citypair = cp.id
JOIN tarifftool_schedule_queue AS sch ON schedule_id = sch.id
 WHERE       b.date = '12/26' AND class = 'b' ORDER BY schedule_id DESC) as qq 
GROUP BY citypair, airline
```

Now i'am just trying as a result get a ordered query. If I do achieve this, i will have no problem grouping my data.

Comment: What's wrong with placing the ORDER-BY-clause at the outer query?

Comment: To add to @Ctx: an Order By in the sub achieves nothing. Think of the Order By as the final formatting of your output while a subquery is merely limiting the amount of rows to be considered by the main query. Good luck.

Comment: since I need to use group by later. I cant group after ordering

Comment: But you can order after grouping. Please show, how you want to group

Comment: added a group by to query

Comment: Hm, this will not be possible, since you would need aggregates for the other fields. Apart from that, you can place the ORDER BY at the very end of the query

Comment: If i put it the end it will first group and then order when i need the opposite.

Comment: Even if this was possible, where do you see the difference?

Comment: `GROUP BY citypair, airline` means you want one result row per citypair and airline. This has nothing to do with the order of the data. So what are you actually trying to achieve? You do know that every column other than citypair and airline you select will be picked arbitrarily from all matches, as long as you don't specify an aggregate function (such as `SUM(fare)` or `MAX(season_from)`), yes?

Answer (score 0):

Use Row_Number in sub query
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY schedule_id)

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY schedule_id DESC ) as RowId,
a.id,
citypair,
a.season,
airline,
class,
fare,
rbd,
season_from,
season_to,
schedule_id,
cp.departure_id,
cp.destination_id,
sch.date_time
FROM tarifftool_price_log as a
JOIN tarifftool_seasons as b ON a.seasonId = b.id
JOIN tarifftool_citypairs as cp ON citypair = cp.id
JOIN tarifftool_schedule_queue AS sch ON schedule_id = sch.id
WHERE       b.date = '12/26' AND class = 'b'  ) as qq 
GROUP BY citypair, airline
```